# How to cancel network request with afnetworking

Tags: afnetworking

Is there a way to cancel all network request (the request started by another method) before I do a network request with AFNetworking
I tried like below but not work:

```
- (void)sendRequest:(NSUInteger)page{


NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClientToCancel = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:aUrl];
[httpClientToCancel cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"product/like"];
[httpClientToCancel release];

... start a new request here .....
```

But not work. I just want to cancel all request (at least the request I wrote above) before I start a new request.

Thank you!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`[[httpClient operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];`

Comment: does this work? I am not sure if my requests are canceling by creating a new instance of httpClient and calling cancelAllOperations.

Comment: This is not working for me... the data keeps syncing to the server even after calling this function. Please help!!

Comment: I think, it's important to mention here, that the failure block of all the canceled operations is still called, and you have to check the error code for -999 which stands for 'operation canceled'. So canceling operations doesn't prevent running the failure block!

Answer (score 11):

Don't Create new `AFHTTPClient` instance.

try `"[self cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"product/like"];`

Comment: What is `self` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Both the other two answers are right. Don't Create new AFHTTPRequestOperationManager instance

```
        @interface OperateCustomerView () <WYPopoverControllerDelegate>{

        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;// = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    }
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
```