# ios disallow cellular for the whole app

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, reachability, cellular-network

Hi I have read some posts and see that I can use "reachability" sample from Apple to check if the current device is run on Wi-Fi or cellular and decide if a connection can be fired. However I have a lots of webviews and HTTP calls in my app on different classes, so I am afraid I have to call the check in every single method which will start a connection. I would like to ask if there is any way to check the status of the network and disallow all traffic on cellular? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Reachability allows you to observe a connection change NSNotification "kReachabilityChangedNotification", which eliminates this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the ReachableViaWiFi network status, which is broadcast via NSNotification. You can setup that up in your code like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NetworkStatus currentNetStatus;
```

...

```
- (void) startListeningForWifi{
            Reachability* hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"hostName"];
            [hostReach startNotifier];

            // reachability set up
            // Observe the kNetworkReachabilityChangedNotification. When that notification is posted, the
            // method "reachabilityChanged" will be called. 
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
}

- (void)reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note{
    Reachability *curReach = [note object];
    self.currentNetStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
}
```

Then it's easy to check the `currentNetStatus` before you make a network call. If that is not equal to `ReachableViaWiFi` then you are not on wifi.

Comment: thanks for your answer its a way to solve my problem. But the case is a little more complicated, say currently I have a connection downloading a file and the network status changes from wifi to cellular, am i able to cancel the connection right away?

Comment: you cancel requests by following this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070175/how-to-cancel-network-request-with-afnetworking)

Comment: does that answer your question?

Comment: thanks a lot. I havent tried yet because I used another approach for this problem.