# Afnetworking cancell the operation and clear the queue

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2. I am doing the syncing process. When I logout the app i want to stop the request and after the login i want to send the new request.

So I am using operation cancel method.

```
[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

when i used this method it was cancelled. But when i start, it is using previous request as well. 
it is calling previous request.

Because here request header having the login token. When I log out and login token should be changed. But here after second login time first request having previous token because of the previous queue.

[How to cancel network request with afnetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070175/how-to-cancel-network-request-with-afnetworking)

Check this as well.